# Type of filter represented by circuit and cutoff frequency

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, cutoff-frequency

What type of filter does this circuit represent? I want to say it's a low-pass filter, but I'm not too sure. Also what would the cutoff frequency formula be in this case (of course that depends on what type of filter this is)? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What type of filter does this circuit represent?

It's a 2nd order RLC high pass filter

> Also what would the cutoff frequency formula be in this case (of
>   course that depends on what type of filter this is)?

Cutoff frequency = ~\$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$

And no, if you have an L and a C forming a filter it's either high-pass, low-pass, band-pass or band-reject BUT in all cases the formula is the same i.e. a low pass 3 dB point is exactly same frequency as the high-pass 3 dB point. Notch and band-pass centre frequencies are identical too.

Low-pass example: -

[image]

High-pass example using the same values: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html).

Answer (score 1):

A quick inspection says that it is not a low pass filter. For small frequencies, the inductor provides low resistance and hence the above circuit will attenuate low frequency signals than high frequency ones.

It is a high pass filter. As the input frequency tends to infinity, the attenuation offered by the circuit tends to 0dB (\$V_o/V_i \rightarrow 1\$).

The transfer function is:
$$\frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)} = \frac{s^2}{s^2 + \frac{R}{L}s + \frac{1}{LC} }$$

You can calculate the cut-off frequency by equating the the magnitude of this function to 0.5 after substituting \$s=jw\$.

Answer (score -1):

as per SPICE simulation it is a HPF with 100khz cut-off frequency.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must be telepathic to have worked out the values from the question dude.